# C++ getting inaccurate results from decimal multiplication

Tags: c++

I am doing some decimal multiplication that requires very high accuracy. For some strange reason, my code is a little inaccurate. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long double x=100, y=0.8;
    cout<<setprecision(100)<<x*y;
}
```

Output:

```
80.00000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

As you can see the first few digits are correct but the last few digits are wrong.
This code is really simple and I think it has no errors. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: `0.8` cannot be represented exactly as a floating point value, (because in binary 4/5 is an infinite fraction). So some inaccuracy is inevitable.

Comment: Ironically the inaccuracy results from the fact that you are doing *binary multiplication*, if you were doing decimal multiplication there would be no inaccuracy. But computers work in binary.

Comment: *For some strange reason,* -- FYI, that "strange reason" has been well-known by computer scientists for decades.  See the duplicate link.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for the help.